# Django rendering error while using request.session in html page?

Tags: python, django, templates

Why i am getting error during rendering??

views.py:

```
def f(r):
   r.session["name"]="testing"
   return render(r,"home.html")
```

home.html:

```
<body>
  <h1>{{ r.session["name"] }}</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use subscripting in a Django template, you can access the value that corresponds to the `session['name']` with `session.name`.

Furthermore the request is pass as `request` to the template, regardless how you name the variable that you pass to the [**`render(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

```
<h1>{{ request.session.name }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DJANGO ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUITX.png)

Assuming that the image linked above pertains to your error, I think I might be of help. Disclaimer though, I am still new to Django so pro users here, please be friendly to this new geek. Here is my suggestion to avoid the error.
Instead of

```
 def f(r):
   r.session["name"]="testing"
   return render(r,"home.html")
```

Try adding a dictionary as an argument. The key in this dictionary ("name" for this instance) will serve as the variable in home.html:

```
def f(r):
   r.session["name"]="testing"
   return render(r,"home.html",{
   "name":r.session["name"]})
```

Then in the HTML page, change this:

```
<body>
  <h1>{{ r.session["name"] }}</h1>
</body>
```

to this:

```
<body>
  <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</body>
```

It seems like your way of coding is not supported by Django's template language. You got it right though. It just needed a variable of its own. Hope I helped!